STM32CubeProgrammer on WSL 2
I am new in doing an embedded programming. I'm trying to flash from WSL 2 and it make an error.
\~ CREATE build_ak-base-kit-stm32l151-application folder
\~ BURNING build_ak-base-kit-stm32l151-application/ak-base-kit-stm32l151-application.bin to target
/home/hieutran/game/tools/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin/STM32_Programmer.sh -c port=SWD -w build_ak-base-kit-stm32l151-application/ak-base-kit-stm32l151-application.bin 0x08003000 -rst
\-------------------------------------------------------------------
STM32CubeProgrammer v2.16.0
\-------------------------------------------------------------------

ST-LINK SN  : 33FF6E06304D453032170643
ST-LINK FW  : V2J37S7
Board       : --
Voltage     : 3.23V
SWD freq    : 4000 KHz
Connect mode: Normal
Reset mode  : Software reset
Error: Unable to list supported devices
Error: Cannot identify the device

I'm able to connect the ST-LINK to WSL.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0483:3748 STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2

Is there any way I can do it in WSL?
Everything works fine in a virtual machine.
